# R: Shifting all dates to one week

Tags: r, posixct, weekday

I think there has been no such question so far, and all the related ones can not solve my problem.

What I have: FB conversation data, with a time stamp for each message

What I want: Plot number of character against time of the week (Monday 14:00 - 356 chars, and so on)

What I found so far: To take advantage of all the fancy plotting functions I should stick to POSIX times. So what I try, is to convert my time to numeric, substract a reference monday, modulo 7, and then convert it back again.

```
dat$zeitpunkt =  strptime(dat$zeitpunkt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") # Convert date from string to date
dat$wday = 
    as.POSIXct(
    as.numeric(dat$zeitpunkt - as.POSIXct("01-02-10 00:00",format="%d-%m-%y %H:%M")) %% 7,
    origin = "2010-02-01")

weekdays(dat$zeitpunkt[1]) # returns "Mittwoch"
weekdays(dat$wday[1])      # returns "Montag"
```

I understand that I could just tweak the reference until I get a wednesday again, but why is happening? Is there a simpler solution?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Just noticed that the time is also screwed up:

```
strftime(dat$wday[1])      # "2010-02-03 01:00:02"
strftime(dat$zeitpunkt[1]) # "2012-11-28 00:50:00"
```

Here I really have no idea what is happening :/

edit2: I want something like this, just with the correct days of the week and times, starting on Monday 00:00 (Or later 5:00, but that is a different story)
[image]

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure your expected output/what's going wrong

Comment: I added I picture, hope it helps :)

Comment: Sorry, i think modulo 7 was stupid... It should be 60*24*7, because the number is in seconds...

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry, i think modulo 7 was stupid... It should be 60*24*7, because the number is in seconds...

I think you're close, but it should be `… %% 7 * 24*60*60`.

(However, I fail to see what you gain from this.)